# TextToSpeech setOnUtteranceCompletedListener always returns -1 error?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I've been working with Android's TTS functions with general success however, one piece of it refuses to work for me; I can not successfully assign an OnUtteranceCompletedListener to my TextToSpeech object.

I've tried implementing OnUtteranceCompletedListener in one of my classes and I've tried creating a new, stand-alone OnUtteranceCompletedListener instance.  Both approaches are simple enough to implement and appear to yield proper listeners without exceptions...yet setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(myListener) ALWAYS returns -1 (ERROR).

The documentation for this seems straight forward.  Has anyone gotten this to work? I'm targeting SDK 4. Are there known issues with this with SDK4/v1.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naturally, after being stumped for more than a day I stumbled onto the answer 15 mins after I asked the question on here.

The answer: the OnUtteranceCompletedListener can only be assigned to the TextToSpeech object AFTER the TTS onInit fires.

I was trying to set the listener immediately after creating the TTS instance.  I moved setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(myListener) to my onInit code and now it returns result code 0 (SUCCESS).

IMO, the TextToSpeech setOnUtteranceCompletedListener [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener)) lacks this detail and should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

There's also another caveat with this listener:
http://groups.google.com/group/tts-for-android/browse_thread/thread/6d5feb49a599e9f9